# Words that must be used together with no meaning alone

Tags: word-choice, word

I really encountered 乒乓 (pingpong/table tennis) and 曱甴 (cockroach).

Are there other words that were created for this usage? Must be used together with no meaning individually?

I feel these words are rather amusing and a bit cheeky.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they are called 连绵词.

There is a list on https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:Chinese_disyllabic_morphemes